# Is there a way that I can access saved entities within a transaction in TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using Nest.js with TypeORM and Postgres.

What I'm trying to do is create and instance of my `User` entity. It has `Membership` and `File` fields that are also entities. Those has One to One relationship with `User`, so are created when `User` is created. If anything goes wrong I want to rollback everything, therefore I'm using a transaction.

This is what I'm doing:

```js
async create(userProcessed: UserProcessed): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const response: UserResponse = {
      message: 'User not created',
      success: false,
      user: undefined,
    };
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      const membership = new Membership();
      membership.membershipState = userProcessed.membershipState;
      membership.membershipType = userProcessed.membershipType;
      const membershipSaved = await queryRunner.manager.save(membership);
      if (!membershipSaved) throw Error();

      const file = new File();
      file.weight = userProcessed.file.weight;
      file.height = userProcessed.file.height;
      const fileSaved = await queryRunner.manager.save(file);
      if (!fileSaved) throw Error(response.message);

      const user = new User();
      user.email = userProcessed.email;
      user.firstName = userProcessed.firstName;
      user.lastName = userProcessed.lastName;
      user.gender = userProcessed.gender;
      user.file = fileSaved;
      user.membership = membershipSaved;
      user.role = userProcessed.role;
      user.birthday = new Date(userProcessed.birthday);
      user.setPassword(userProcessed.password);

      const userSaved = await this.userRepository.save(user);
      console.log(userSaved);
      if (!userSaved) throw Error(response.message);

      response.success = true;
      response.message = 'User created';
      response.user = userSaved;

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      throw Error(response.message);
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

The problem comes when user is created. As I'm using an transaction, nothing is saved into the DB until I call `await queryRunner.commitTransaction();` (as it has to be). As result, the `membership` and `file` that I'm trying to use as foreign key doesn't really exists.

Is there a way that I can solve this in the same transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought.

I just found that I can set `{ cascade: ['insert'] }` in the `@OneToOne` annotation in `User`. With that, there is no need to save the `File` or `Membership` before `User`, are saved when `User` is saved.

In `user.entity.ts`:

```js
  ...
  @OneToOne(type => Membership, { cascade: ['insert'] })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'membership_id' })
  membership: Membership;

  @OneToOne(type => File, { cascade: ['insert'] })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'file_id' })
  file: File;
  ...
```

In `user.service.ts`

```js
  async create(userProcessed: UserProcessed): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const response: UserResponse = {
      message: 'User not created',
      success: false,
      user: undefined,
    };
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();
    try {
      const membership = new Membership();
      membership.membershipState = userProcessed.membershipState;
      membership.membershipType = userProcessed.membershipType;

      const file = new File();
      file.weight = userProcessed.file.weight;
      file.height = userProcessed.file.height;

      const user = new User();
      user.email = userProcessed.email;
      user.firstName = userProcessed.firstName;
      user.lastName = userProcessed.lastName;
      user.gender = userProcessed.gender;
      user.file = file;
      user.membership = membership;
      user.role = userProcessed.role;
      user.birthday = new Date(userProcessed.birthday);
      user.setPassword(userProcessed.password);

      const userSaved = await this.userRepository.save(user);
      console.log(userSaved);
      if (!userSaved) throw Error(response.message);

      response.success = true;
      response.message = 'User created';
      response.user = userSaved;

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      throw Error(response.message);
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

And with that everything works as a charm!